# Adding a custom link to a top menu / navigation based on a csutom attribute of that category

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, topmenu

Based on a custom category attribute created I want to show a link (right next to the category in drop-down menu), on top navigation.
I tried to achieve via `render.ptml` where the menus are created, but I couldn't get a category id.
For parent id i was able to get get id from:

```
$catname= $child->getId();
$catname = explode('-',"$catname");
$parntid=(int)$catname['2'];)
```

How can I do that for all categories?

Comment: When do you want to show this link ? only in category page or in every page ?

Comment: @RajeevKTomy   I want to show in top navigation (dropdown ) , on every page (its like buying guide link right next to that category in navigation)